# change boot order in rc.d

Tags: linux, rc

I currently have scripts in the rc.# S## ...

one of my scripts is called:
S20cheese and another is called S19Moo. How would I properly update these run orders e.g. S20cheese -> S15cheese.

Is it as simple as renaming the files in every rc.2 / rc.3 etc etc or will this break things?

I am trying to set the run order as I need cheese to run at 30 seconds into the boot but loads of other processes are running before it

Comment: It is as simple as just changing them provided you don't run any configuration tools such as `chkconfig` that will change them back when run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update-rc.d -f cheese remove
update-rc.d cheese defaults 15
```